# Javascript negative lookbehind same character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm facing the following problem - I've got a sequence:

```
[yyy]zyyyyz[yyy]zyyyyyyyyz[yyy]
```

This is the input I need to match (except [] which I used to highlight the required matches).
My regex should match only the sequence of 'y' which has exactly 3 characters. So

```
yyy - should match
zyyyz - should match
zyyyy - should not match
yyyyz - should not match
```

It's easy to implement the first part of the regex. Of course

```
y{3}(?!y)
```

matches all sequences of y which consist of 3 characters and are not followed by another y. The problem is javascript doesn't support lookbehinds so there is no easy way to check for preceeding characters... how to achieve this? I think I cannot reverse the string... I mean there can be multiple matching sequences, not only one so it won't do any good.

Comment: What's your actual input?

Comment: Just updated to question to be more specific

Comment: Then why you added `z` before and after in this `zyyyz` ?

Comment: Because I would like to cover all possibilities. If there is a long string of y but there's a fragment of 3 separated from others by any other characters it should be a match.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I believe it is impossible to make an exact match (group 0) in JavaScript for this. However, `(?:[^y]|^)(y{3})(?!y)` should match the group 1 to your requirements for all situations, including two instances being separated by a single non-`y`, start of string and end of string. Equivalently, `([^y]|^)(y{3})(?!y)/` will match the group 2, leaving group 1 to restore the first character that needs to be consumed by the regular expression if you are doing replacement. Example:

```
var re = /([^y]|^)(y{3})(?!y)/g;
"yyy0yyy0000yyyyyy00yy0yyyy0000yyy".replace(re, "$1---")
// => "---0---0000yyyyyy00yy0yyyy0000---"
"[yyy]zyyyyz[yyy]zyyyyyyyyz[yyy]".replace(re, "$1---")
// => "[---]zyyyyz[---]zyyyyyyyyz[---]"
"yyyzyyyyzyyyzyyyyyyyyzyyy".replace(re, "$1---")
// => "---zyyyyz---zyyyyyyyyz---"
```

Comment: The `[]` in the question is used to highlight required matches and not in the actual input. It does not make your example wrong, though

Comment: @nhahtdh: Good point. It makes no difference, but edited in the bracketless version.

Comment: But isn't the preceeding character a match too? I mean when i try it on something like 'dd-MM-yyy' i get '-yyy' as a match in javascript (and regexpal)

Comment: It is, which is why I specifically said `yyy` is a match for group 1 (or group 2, in the second regexp and in the examples), rather than the whole match (group 0).

Answer (score 0):

***Matching***... So you're trying to validate inputs. `TRUE` when there is three isolated sequence of `y` in the string otherwise return `FALSE`.

Then I came with this regex:

```
(?=(?:[^y]|^)(yyy)(?:[^y]|$))
```

In which you can also work with all captured `yyy` groups.

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/lR1vU0/1)**